# Error al cargar clase PDO en servidor Nginx

Tags: pdo, nginx

Hola a la gran comunidad de Stackoverflow.

Tenemos un servidor Kimsufi dedicado donde tenemos múltiples aplicaciones cargadas a través de Nginx. La semana pasada, el servidor se "atascó" y tuvo que reiniciarse. Desde ese día no hemos podido iniciar algunas aplicaciones.

Muchos de estos devuelven el siguiente error:

```
"Class 'PDO' not found"

2020/10/19 09:22:51 [error] 5777#5777: *537 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ')' in /var/www/intranet.mysite.es/public/3rdparty/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DriverManager.php on line 195" while reading response header from upstream, client: 79.148.133.250, server: intranet.mysite.es, request: "GET /status.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "intranet.mysite.es"
```

Ahora mismo estamos cargando PHP versión 7.3, no 7.2. Introduciendo php -v compruebo que la versión que carga es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con PHP -m verifiqué los módulos cargados y aparecen módulos PDO:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso, ¿dónde puede estar el problema? En nuestro caso estamos cargando todo desde Nginx, por lo que hemos reiniciado ese servicio en varias ocasiones.

Muchas gracias a todos por su ayuda.

Comment: Hola, si cabe la posibilidad en lugar de agregar imagenes intenta poner siempre el texto ya que muchas veces las imagenes caducan en el servidor donde las has hospedado y tu pregunta  pierde valor de cara al futuro

Comment: tiene pinta de se del archivo de configuracion, `sites-enabled` dime cual es tu document root